# How to identify Azure Diagnostics version on worker role

Tags: azure, azure-deployment, azure-diagnostics

Is there a way to identify azure diagnostics version running on azure worker role?

I am using Azure SDK 2.5 in my project and have configured diagnostics.wadcfgx for worker role with event source configuration as below.

I am deploying worker role from visual studio and I think it should be automatically deploying latest azure diagnostics. It worked correctly on first deployment and I was able to see logs from event source. But it didnt work on subsequent deployments.

diagnostics.wadcfgx:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DiagnosticsConfiguration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2010/10/DiagnosticsConfiguration">
  <PublicConfig xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2010/10/DiagnosticsConfiguration">
    <WadCfg>
      <DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration overallQuotaInMB="4096">
        <DiagnosticInfrastructureLogs scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter="Error" />
        <Directories scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M">
          <IISLogs containerName="wad-iis-logfiles" />
          <FailedRequestLogs containerName="wad-failedrequestlogs" />
        </Directories>
        <PerformanceCounters scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M">
          <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Memory\Available MBytes" sampleRate="PT3M" />
          <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Web Service(_Total)\ISAPI Extension Requests/sec" sampleRate="PT3M" />
          <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Web Service(_Total)\Bytes Total/Sec" sampleRate="PT3M" />
          <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\ASP.NET Applications(__Total__)\Requests/Sec" sampleRate="PT3M" />
          <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\ASP.NET Applications(__Total__)\Errors Total/Sec" sampleRate="PT3M" />
          <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\ASP.NET\Requests Queued" sampleRate="PT3M" />
          <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\ASP.NET\Requests Rejected" sampleRate="PT3M" />
          <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" sampleRate="PT3M" />
        </PerformanceCounters>
        <WindowsEventLog scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M">
          <DataSource name="Application!*" />
        </WindowsEventLog>
        <EtwProviders>
          <EtwEventSourceProviderConfiguration provider="YalEventLogger" scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M">
            <Event id="1" eventDestination="WADYalEventLogsTable" />
            <Event id="2" eventDestination="WADYalValuesTable" />
            <Event id="3" eventDestination="WADYalMessagesTable" />
            <DefaultEvents />
          </EtwEventSourceProviderConfiguration>
        </EtwProviders>
        <CrashDumps>
          <CrashDumpConfiguration processName="WaIISHost.exe" />
          <CrashDumpConfiguration processName="WaWorkerHost.exe" />
          <CrashDumpConfiguration processName="w3wp.exe" />
        </CrashDumps>
        <Logs scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M" scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter="Error" />
      </DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration>
    </WadCfg>
    <StorageAccount>yalnewwadexample</StorageAccount>
  </PublicConfig>
  <PrivateConfig xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2010/10/DiagnosticsConfiguration">
    <StorageAccount name="yalnewwadexample" endpoint="https://core.windows.net/" />
  </PrivateConfig>
  <IsEnabled>true</IsEnabled>
</DiagnosticsConfiguration>
```

Comment: Are you updating your deployments from Visual Studio itself?

Comment: Yes Gaurav, from VS 2013.

Comment: Is your cloud service role using Reserved IPs?

Comment: No, its not using Reserved IPs.